# Ссылка с атрибутом target = '_blank'

Tags: html, jquery

Нужно открывать ссылку в новой вкладке

Вот изначальная ссылка

```
 <a class="product-descr-wrap statistic" object="<?= $model->id ?>" href="http://google.com.ua" target="_blank">Ссылка</a>
```

Вешаю событие при клике на класс statistic. Это нужно, чтобы считать количество переходов по ссылке. Отправляется запрос ajax, в контроллере обрататывается и возвращается response. Если он успешный - то открывать ссылку в новом окне.

```
$('.statistic').on('click', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/site/visit?id='+$(this).attr('object'),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success: function(response) {
            if(response){
                var url = $('.statistic').attr('href');
                window.location.href = url;
                // target = '_blank';
            }
        }
    }); return false;
});
```

Если открывать методом `window.open(url, '_blank');` - работает, но проблема в том, что нужно давать разрешение, так как браузер изначально блокирует ссылку, и думает что это попап. Хотя, если разрешить - откывает в новой вкладке, а не в новом окне

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно обойти эту блокировку ?

Comment: как выглядит элемент с классом _'.statistic'_? Скорее всего достаточно ему просто сделать `click`, если это уже ссылка. И еще добавь, где у тебя расположен код приведенный в вопросе?

Comment: Тэг <a>, если вы об этом  - <a class="product-descr-wrap statistic" href="current_href">`

Comment: Да, об этом, добавляй это тоже в вопрос. На нем есть какие-то обработчики?

Comment: Нет, конкретно на этот клас только клик, в котором идет ajax запрос. Вы думаете пробелма в самой ссылке? `console.log($('.statistic').attr('href'))` - все выводит корректно

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду, что ей можно добавить `target="_blank"`  и при клике по этой ссылке - новая страница сама откроется в новой вкладке

Comment: То же самое, открывает, только после подтверждения, браузер по прежнему считает ссылку - pop-up window

Comment: можешь сделать [mcve]? что именно ты сделал?

Comment: переписал вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.statistic').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/site/visit?id='+$(this).attr('object'),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success: function(response) {
            if(response){
                var a = document.querySelector('a');
                a.click();
            }
        }
    }); return false;
});
```